# Custom Status triggering Custom Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom trigger called "Shipped" which seems to work perfectly in my list of options.

```
function add_new_order_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {

    // include our custom email class
    require( 'includes/class-wc-shipped-order-email.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['WC_Shipped_Order_Email'] = new WC_Shipped_Order_Email();

    return $email_classes;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_new_order_woocommerce_email' );

function register_shipped_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipped', array(
        'label'                     => 'Shipped',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shipped_order_status' );

function add_new_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-shipped'] = 'Shipped';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_new_to_order_statuses' );
```

I have been having issues trying to get this email to trigger when the status is changed to my custom status provided above. I have searched the internet for multiple examples and possible solutions to my problem but have been unable to find anything that helps.

The email template in the code has been created and is in the correct directory location.

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * A custom Shipped Order WooCommerce Email class
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @extends \WC_Email
 */
class WC_Shipped_Order_Email extends WC_Email {

    public function __construct() {

        // set ID, this simply needs to be a unique name
        $this->id = 'wc_shipped_order';

        // this is the title in WooCommerce Email settings
        $this->title = 'Shipped';

        // defines the email for customers only
        $this->customer_email = true;

        // this is the description in WooCommerce email settings
        $this->description = 'Shipped order notification emails are sent when a customers order has been shipped.';

        // these are the default heading and subject lines that can be overridden using the settings
        $this->heading = 'Order Shipped';
        $this->subject = 'Order Shipped';

        // these define the locations of the templates that this email should use, we'll just use the new order template since this email is similar
        $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-shipped-order.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-shipped-order.php';

        // Trigger on new paid orders
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_shipped', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_shipped',  array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

        // Call parent constructor to load any other defaults not explicity defined here
        parent::__construct();

        // this sets the recipient to the settings defined below in init_form_fields()
        $this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient' );

        // if none was entered, just use the WP admin email as a fallback
        if ( ! $this->recipient )
            $this->recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the email should actually be sent and setup email merge variables
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function trigger( $order_id ) {

        // bail if no order ID is present
        if ( ! $order_id )
            return;

        // setup order object
        $this->object = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        // replace variables in the subject/headings
        $this->find[] = '{order_date}';
        $this->replace[] = date_i18n( woocommerce_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );

        $this->find[] = '{order_number}';
        $this->replace[] = $this->object->get_order_number();

        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() )
            return;

        // woohoo, send the email!
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }

    /**
     * Get email subject.
     *
     * @since  3.1.0
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_default_subject() {
        return __( 'Your order has been shipped', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    /**
     * Get email heading.
     *
     * @since  3.1.0
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_default_heading() {
        return __( 'Thanks for shopping with us', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    /**
     * Get content html.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        return wc_get_template_html(
            $this->template_html, array(
                'order'         => $this->object,
                'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
                'sent_to_admin' => false,
                'plain_text'    => false,
                'email'         => $this,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get content plain.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        return wc_get_template_html(
            $this->template_plain, array(
                'order'         => $this->object,
                'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
                'sent_to_admin' => false,
                'plain_text'    => true,
                'email'         => $this,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initialise settings form fields.
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {
        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled'    => array(
                'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => __( 'Enable this email notification', 'woocommerce' ),
                'default' => 'yes',
            ),
            'subject'    => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Subject', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'desc_tip'    => true,
                /* translators: %s: list of placeholders */
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'Available placeholders: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<code>{site_title}, {order_date}, {order_number}</code>' ),
                'placeholder' => $this->get_default_subject(),
                'default'     => '',
            ),
            'heading'    => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Email heading', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'desc_tip'    => true,
                /* translators: %s: list of placeholders */
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'Available placeholders: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<code>{site_title}, {order_date}, {order_number}</code>' ),
                'placeholder' => $this->get_default_heading(),
                'default'     => '',
            ),
            'email_type' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Email type', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => __( 'Choose which format of email to send.', 'woocommerce' ),
                'default'     => 'html',
                'class'       => 'email_type wc-enhanced-select',
                'options'     => $this->get_email_type_options(),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
        );
    }


} // end \WC_Shipped_Order_Email class

function fabricdeluxe_shipped_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_shipped';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'fabricdeluxe_shipped_woocommerce_email_actions' );
```

A lot of this coding was sourced via other sources and customised to suit my application, however I have been stuck on this one problem for so long I have no decided to resorting to this amazing website to get some expert opinions on what I could possibly be doing wrong or where I may find a solution. (I prefer to learn myself, but my brain can only take so much before it becomes annoyingly hard to solve haha!)

Any help is greatly appreciated!